# Back button functionality using ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement which needs me to redirect an user to previous page on his browsing history. I am using ASP.net MVC 1.0. I do NOT want to use javascript to achieve this. Any pointers?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Request.UrlReferrer` property to render out a link. Maybe like this:

```
<a href="<%= Request.UrlReferrer %>">Back</a>
```

Comment: This will not work if the browser blocks the referrer... and many people seem to do that nowadays!

Comment: I've never had that problem to be honest - i guess the OP will have to decide whether this is a risk for his site though

Comment: It's fairly common to block the referrer when you are behind a corporate firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a parameter "returnUrl" in your action, and then return a RedirectResult. It should do.

For info, take a look at the Account controller, from the default template ASP.NET MVC project on VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

And what about:

```
<a class="ImageBtn" href="previous.html" onClick="history.back();return false;">Go back</a>
```

In this case you can asign an image so it looks better.

Comment: That _is_ using javascript ... and adding an image will increase the page load ... better to implement prettiness using CSS.

Comment: in fact the idea is to use css in the "class" also did not notice the "NOT"